# Warning unchecked call to 'getposition(T)'

Tags: android

I'm retrieving some default from a database on application start and I'm using it to set the selected value of a spinner item in my activity.

```
       if( key.equals("default Altitude Units")) {
           Spinner s = ((Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinAltitudeUnits));
           ArrayAdapter a = (ArrayAdapter) s.getAdapter();
           s.setSelection( a.getPosition(result.getString(2)));
       }
```

The code works fine however the problem is that i'm getting a warning in Android Studio that says *Warning unchecked call to 'getposition(T)' as a member of raw type 'android.widget.ArrayAdapter'* on the a.getPosition call.

I'm happy that it's working but being new to android and Java I want to understand and eliminate as many warnings as possible from my code so any help in getting rid of this warning would be most welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the position from some string. sting 2 in this case. A ArrayAdapter can contain many types. Integers for example. In your case it is not clear what your ArrayAdapter is containing.

Use this instead:

```
    ArrayAdapter<String> a = (ArrayAdapter<String>) s.getAdapter();
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to paramaterize your ArrayAdapter.  Do so with the following code:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> a = (ArrayAdapter<String>) s.getAdapter();
```

That is, if your ArrayAdapter contains strings.

EDIT: woops, got beat by a few seconds.